# iOS 7 Google AdMob not appearing

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, admob

I am trying to add an AdMob banner on an application.  I am using iOS 7 both simulator and iPhone device.

My code is as follows:

```
-(GADRequest *)createRequest {
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, nil];
return request;
}
```

When I run this on the iPhone 5s device I get the following error in the console:

```
<Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ @"7523f590b222af575517f669f4d63632" ];

<Google> Invalid Request: {
errors = "Cannot determine request type. Is your ad unit id correct?";
"google.afma.Notify_dt" = 1389504628864;
"request_id" = 1;
"request_scenario" = "offline_empty";
type = unknown;
"use_webview_loadurl" = 0;
}
```

If I change my code to what is suggested, i.e.

```
-(GADRequest *)createRequest {
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = @[ @"7523f590b222af575517f669f4d63632" ];
return request;
}
```

I get the exact same error message.

Now when I run this in the simulator I get this error message:

```
<Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ];
```

And if I change my code to what Google suggests, i.e.:

```
-(GADRequest *)createRequest {
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ];
return request;
}
```

Again I get the same error message.  Is there any problem with AdMob and iOS 7? Is there something wrong in my implementation?  I went through the AdMob documentation and everything is according to what Google suggests.

Hope somebody can help me with that.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you find the fix as I am having the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your ad unit id to your GADBannerView.

Something like:

```
self.bannerView.adUnitID = @"your ad unit id from the admob site"
```

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#ios

Answer (score -1):

in first, yes, set your publisher ID

in second, restart (kill) emulator.

it helps me many times.

in 3-rd, if #2 not helps, kill emulator, select another emulated device and run again.
don't know why, but it helps too. XCode 5